# How to run mypyc in Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, mypyc

How does one install/run mypyc on Anaconda/Spyder?
The documentation (https://mypyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) does not address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing a wheel from here: https://github.com/mypyc/mypy_mypyc-wheels/releases

Pick the one for your PC type (Windows, Mac, Linux) then open an Anaconda Command Prompt, go to where the file is downloaded and type: `pip install filename.whl`

For directions on how to use it read here: https://mypyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Note compiling is done from the command prompt, not in Python.  You should probably check out Pythran it's a more actively developed Python to native CPython module compiler, and it's pretty easy to use.